# What does a double-dollar sign ($$) mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, operators

I'm trying to hack together a new file format writer for pandoc using [LaTeX.hs](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/LaTeX.hs#L374) as a guide. Extensive use of a `$$` operator is made, but I can't find this in the [Haskell syntax documentation](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/syntax-iso.html) or even references to in in other projects. Here is an example:

```
let align dir txt = inCmd "begin" dir $$ txt $$ inCmd "end" dir
```

This almost looks like a concatenation operator of some kind, yet I can't make out how this is different from other concatenation operations. What is this operator, how does it work, and where is it documented?

Comment: It's just a library-defined operator. You'd search for it within pandoc and the libraries pandoc uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pandoc defines its own pretty-printing library internally but the operations (and the name of the type, `Doc`) are standard in Haskell pretty printing libraries.  Pandoc also defines other familiars like `vcat`, `hsep`, `<+>` and so on; there are many pretty printing modules around, but they always support these operations.

```
 > import Text.PrettyPrint
 > text "hello" <> text "world"
 helloworld
 > text "hello" <+> text "world"
 hello world
 > text "hello" $$ text "world" 
 hello
 world
 > text "hello" <+> text "world" $$ text "goodbye" <+> text "world"
 hello world
 goodbye world
```

`ghci` here displays 'what the document will look like', crudely speaking.

Comment: Afaik `base` does not contain the module `Text.PrettyPrint`, do you mean the package [`pretty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pretty)? And I don't think GHCi contains any special rules for displaying `Doc`, are you sure its not simply how the `Show` instance is defined?

Comment: Right its not in base, it's a ghc boot package, so you have it if you ghc.

Comment: What `ghci` version (or year) did they separated the base modules from the other modules?

Answer (score 5):

This is a job for [Hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%28%24%24%29+package%3Apandoc) or [Hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28%24%24%29+%2Bpandoc). It's an operator defined in [Text.Pandoc.Pretty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.15.1.1/docs/Text-Pandoc-Pretty.html#v:-36--36-).

> ```
> ($$) :: Doc -> Doc -> Doc infixr 5
> ```
>
> `a $$ b` puts `a` above `b`.

Basically, it will make sure that `a` and `b` are on different lines, which leads to nicer LaTeX output:

```
\begin{dir}
txt
\end{dir}
```

Comment: Any reason you posted this as community wiki? Just checking to make sure it wasn't a mistake.

Comment: @BoltClock, well, the answer is more or less just the result of a Hoogle search, so it wasn't taking any effort (and it doesn't feel right to get +50 just for that D:). Also, `($$)` documentation might change in the future. That being said, any reason why I didn't get any notification for your comment?

Comment: Fair enough. And I didn't realize it wouldn't ping - guessing it's because it's a wiki answer!

Comment: Oh. Then I should probably have a look at other Wiki answers too.

Comment: My vote? This is worth 50 rep. Besides giving me the fish you found which answers my question, you also showed me how to fish. That's useful, and exactly what SO is about. Ever if it's not an thesis length answer and this was an easy question, this doesn't fit what the CW format was designed for and does fit the regular answer pattern.